# Does more traffic to my website improve SERP?

Tags: blog, search-results, traffic

I have a few very popular blog posts that rank highly on keywords I am not focusing on.
My question is does my website's SERP benefits from this high traffic?

Is there an official information out there to inform on this?

Answer (score 1):

The traffic doesn't have effect on SERPs ranking. Otherwise, there would be so many SEO professional who would pay many people to click on their sites. Actually, as you most probably know, the contrary is true: more your site ranks well on SERPs, more visitors you have.

Answer (score 1):

Directly? No. Indirectly? ***Maybe***.

The more traffic that you have, the more likely it is that people will share your content. For example, if an article on your website goes "viral", then there's the possibility that links to said article will be:

1. Shared on some of the various social networks (leading to even more traffic).
2. Shared by bloggers.
3. Posted on forums.
4. Shared on some of the various niche, news and entertainment websites that are out there.

In cases like this, you will probably see an increase in your SERP rankings.

Basically, in the world of SEO, the big tend to get bigger, simply because they're getting far more attention.